# ContentResolver query with timestamp

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I have service which must run if the difference between current date and dealdate is less than 15 minutes.

I have DBHelper class which creates table:

```
public class ToDoDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private ArrayList<ToDoClass> todoitems;

private final String DATABASE_NAME = "deals.db";

public ToDoDBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    final  String Create_Table_Query = "CREATE TABLE "+ ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.TABLE_NAME+" ( "+
    ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column+" TIMESTAMP ,"+
            ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.end_dealDate_column+" TIMESTAMP ,"+
            ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.shortdescription_column+" TEXT  NOT NULL ,"+
            ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.fulldescription_column+" TEXT NOT NULL "+");";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Create_Table_Query);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}
```

}

and I have contentresolver query in which I want use selection criteria:

```
 Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            selection,
            null,
            ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column+" DESC");
```

But I do not know how to write selection. In selection I need to  get difference between ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column and currentDate.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

@Shriyansh Gautam thanks for your answer. 
I found the solution of my problem. Now I am using query method of SQLiteDatabase class. Here is my code,  and it works for me.

```
   Date curDate = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(curDate);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+15));


    String selection = ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column+" >= ?";
    String [] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis())};

    String notifText = null;
    ToDoDBHelper toDoDBHelper  = new ToDoDBHelper(context,"deals", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = toDoDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("deals",
            null,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column+" ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
       long FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15*60*1000;
       String dateFormatSQLite = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; //verify timestamp format in your case
       String timezone = "GMT+0.00"; //use your timestamp
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatSQLite);
       sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
       String date = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - FIFTEEN_MINUTES));
```

If in your case the value is stored in epoch in your sqlite database then you can do this

```
       long FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15*60*1000;
       String date = System.currentTimeMillis() - FIFTEEN_MINUTES;


      Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column+" <= ?",
        new String[]{date},
        ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column+" DESC");
```

Comment: Maybe I must convert date to timestamp:
String date = "1410293471300";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ date };

Comment: I have already given that to you in my answer new String[]{date}

Comment: it is very strange. If I check the value of ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column valur returned like 1410293471300 not like in timestampformat.

Comment: So I must something like this:

Date curDate = New Date();
String date = String.valueof(curDate.getTime());

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column+" <= ?",
        new String[]{date},
        ToDoDatabase.ToDoDatabaseEntry.start_dealDate_column+" DESC");

Comment: did this worked @Renat Ahmetshin? See the updated answer

Comment: unfortunatly not. It does not help me. I think that the problem in selection parameter and selection args parameters.